# Jquery class for list elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, list

I'm trying to adapt a JS plugin and I need to give numerical classes to a series of `li` items

This is the code at the moment and I would like to add a `class` or a `data` attribute in order to be able to select them individually

```
var li = '<li><a href="#' + link + 'class "><span></span></a>';
```

Comment: Why do you need to add a specific (and ugly) incremental `id` to each element? It would be better to instead add a single click event handler to all the `a` elements and use the `this` keyword within the handler to reference the element which raised the event.

Comment: I have to change the css of every single element

Comment: Try [Jqurey to add class](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/) on group of elements `$('li a').addClass("myclass")`

Comment: As you say, you can use "data" attribute : https://jsfiddle.net/zetcxofq/

Comment: you can add class by index as well `$( "li a" ).addClass(function( index ) {return "item-" + index;});`

Comment: @Braj the fact is that the `li` elements are genreted automatically so I have to crete a `var` in which every element get the class based on is position in the `ul`

Comment: You can get the index of `<li>` under `<ul>` and based on that you can add class on `<a>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with [JQuery addClass()](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/) to add class on based on its position.

For example

```
$( "ul li" ).addClass(function( index ) {
  return "item-" + index;
});
```

This example adds the class "item-0" to the first `<li>` and "item-1" to the second.

---

In the same way you can add class on `<a>` under each `<li>`.

```
$( "ul li" ).each(function( index1 ) {      
   $(this).find('a').addClass(function( index2 ) {
       return "item-" + (index1 * 10 + index2) ;
   });
});
```